# Final FormWizard redirects to first step

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I basically used the django-formtool form wizard to handle saving of my form.

1. User enters the "username" and "repository" on first step.
2. repository is cloned
3. User enters "inventory" and "user" on second step.
4. I'm expecting that after the final submit, it will just save the data

I'm having trouble when I try to save on the final step of the wizard,
I returns me to the first step. With the expected ValidationError that the repository exists, because on my `views.py` execute the `clone_repository()` method.

Below are the relevant code I currently have.

**views.py**

```
class PlaybookWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def process_step(self, form):
        if self.steps.current == '0':
            form.clone_repository()
        if self.steps.current == '1':
            form.save()
        return super(PlaybookWizard, self).process_step(form)

    def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/playbooks')
```

**forms.py**

```
def check_path_exists(repository, host_inventory=None):
    if host_inventory:
        os.chdir(settings.PLAYBOOK_DIR + repository)
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        return os.path.exists(os.path.join(current_dir, host_inventory))
    return os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.PLAYBOOK_DIR, repository))

def get_dir_name(repository):
    return os.path.join(settings.PLAYBOOK_DIR, repository)

def get_remote_repo_url(username, repository):
    return "https://github.com/{0}/{1}.git".format(
            username, repository
    )


class AnsibleForm1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Playbook
        fields = ['repository', 'username']

    def clean_repository(self):
        if check_path_exists(self.cleaned_data['repository']):
            raise ValidationError("Repository already exists")
        return self.cleaned_data['repository']

    def clone_repository(self):
        repository = self.cleaned_data['repository']
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']

        dir_name = get_dir_name(repository)
        remote_url = get_remote_repo_url(username, repository)
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(dir_name))
        repo = git.Repo.init(dir_name)
        origin = repo.create_remote('origin', remote_url)
        origin.fetch()
        origin.pull(origin.refs[0].remote_head)

class AnsibleForm2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Playbook
        fields = ['inventory', 'user']
```

**models.py**

```
class Playbook(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=39, default="")
    repository = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    inventory = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="hosts")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="ubuntu")
    directory = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=False, default="dir")

    def get_dir_name(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.PLAYBOOK_DIR, self.repository)

    def format_directory(self):
        directory = self.repository.lower()
        directory = directory.replace(" ","-")
        return directory

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.directory = self.format_directory()
        super(Playbook, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You should save the forms in `done()` method. Also clone the repository after saving the forms in `done()`.

Comment: thanks @Rohan your comment gave me the idea to the correct solution